# Passing a 2d vector to a function

Tags: c++, vector, types

I have a 2d vector of integers :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
```

And I want to call a function on this object.
The function is :

```
int coverTransactions(int k, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix ) { //k nombre de clusters
    int compteur = 0;
    for(int t = 0; t != 11; t++) {
        compteur = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i != k; i++) {
            if(matrix[t][i] == 1)
                compteur++;
        }
        if(compteur != 1)
            return -1; //on retourne -1 si la transaction n'appartient pas à un et un seul cluster
    }
    return 0;//si tout se passe correctement, cad t appartient à un et un seul cluster on retourne 0
}
```

Don't pay attention to the French comments, it's just to explain how returning values are linked to the problem I want to solve but it doesn't affect the understanding of the code ...

For some reason, when calling the function this way :

```
std::cout << coverTransactions(3, &matrix) << std::endl;
```

I get the following error :

```
 coderror: cannot convert ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >*’ to ‘int (*)[3]’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int coverTransactions(int, int (*)[3])’
```

I don't understand why because they are the same type ...

Comment: Try dropping `&` from `&matrix`. The argument is passed by reference, not by pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately, I get the same error ...

Comment: @GuillaumeLeseur: No, you don't. I just tried it, and that fixes it. If not, then you have not shown us the real code.

Comment: I know what I'm saying dude

Comment: The error message doesn't correspond to posted code. You are trying to compile something different from what you have posted.

Comment: @GuillaumeLeseur: You may know what you are saying, but your own code here disagrees with you.

Comment: Your code is working fine, after the following the changes suggested in answers. I don't see why the code isn't compiling for you. @GuillaumeLeseur

Comment: Ok my bad, in one of the .hpp files, a function was still taking a &matrix as parameter

Comment: Your edit would still have the same, working fix (removing `&` from the call). So there is still more to your code than you have posted. In the future, you should consider the hints at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get more useful answers.

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it solved your issue. @GuillaumeLeseur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing happening here is a `pass by reference`, which is different from `pass by pointer`, where you pass the address of a variable into a function (when calling it) and the function's definition accepts a pointer. Here, you are basically passing a pointer to the vector as an argument and thus doing a `pass by pointer` :

```
coverTransactions(3, &matrix)
```

, whereas according to your function's definition, a `pass by reference` is happening here, hence, simply pass the vector as it is in the function :

```
coverTransactions(3, matrix)
```

The difference between the above two methods are that a `pointer` can be `NULL`, but `references` are never `NULL`, and hence we are sure that we are referencing a valid variable. That's why it's a good practice to use `references` whenever you can, and use `pointers` only when you have to.

Comment: *"copies the reference"* is not how I would explain passing by reference. In particular, references have nothing to do with copying at all. The implementation *may* copy an address under the hood, but that's not relevant from a C++ language point of view.

Comment: Updated my answer @ChristianHackl, please lift the down-vote. :)

Comment: I did not downvote. If I had to *guess*, it was the OP himself who downvoted both you and me (see comments).

Comment: Ok, maybe he doesn't understand what's the real bug.

Comment: In any case, I hate to be so picky, but in the C++11 era we're living in, I'd also stop talking about `NULL` and always use `nullptr` instead. As for "trading" upvotes, I'd like to refrain from that, thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah you are right, but still a lot of people including me don't code in C++11, and everyone knows `NULL`, hence, no harm in using it !

Comment: I think the general consensus at Stack Overflow is that "C++" always refers to the latest official version, unless stated otherwise. This does not exclude questions and answers about C++98 or C++03, of course, but one should then explicitly mention that.

Comment: I did not downvote anybody ... I understand the answer and assume I was wrong by using a & but still, I get the error that's just what I'm saying ... I'm using c++98 btw (I don't have the choice I'm in University and they don't want to use c++11)

Comment: Can you post more snippets of your code ? From the information given, it's hard to debug. @GuillaumeLeseur

Comment: @GuillaumeLeseur: Three people have given you the fix for the code you posted. We cannot give you a fix for code you do not show us. Please edit your question and post the relevant code; repeatedly saying that you still get the error is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to pass a **pointer** to `matrix` instead of a reference. Remove the `&`:

```
std::cout << coverTransactions(3, matrix) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int coverTransactions(int k, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &matrix ) { //k nombre de clusters
    int compteur = 0;
    for(int t = 0; t != 11; t++) {
        compteur = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i != k; i++) {
            if(matrix[t][i] == 1)
                compteur++;
        }
        if(compteur != 1)
            return -1; //on retourne -1 si la transaction n'appartient pas à un et un seul cluster
    }
    return 0;//si tout se passe correctement, cad t appartient à un et un seul cluster on retourne 0
}
```

So, when calling the function:

```
std::cout << coverTransactions(3, matrix) << std::endl;
```

Now, it`s good to go!